# Regex excluding all groups matched by negative lookahead

Tags: html, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I have a regex to parse folder and file names out from a block of HTML code, and exclude filenames with the extension `.ini`.

My current regex: `/href="([\w]+)(\.[\w]+)*/ig`

1. Matches group one: 1+ word characters
2. Matches group two 0+ times: `.` then 1+ word characters
3. Flags: match case insensitive and as many as possible

I have tried to use negative lookahead (what I think is the proper solution) time and time again to remove a match if it has the extension `.ini`.  Sadly, I have failed my mission, and here I am.  I chose not to include my attempts above because it would just pollute the question

---

From reading all over the internet:

- [Negative Lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
- Match strings not containing a string: https://www.regextester.com/15
- [Regular expression for excluding file types .exe and .js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23178316/regular-expression-for-excluding-file-types-exe-and-js)

To restate:

- What I have is two groups.
- What I think I should do is use negative lookahead to match for `.ini`, and then if it matches, exclude **all** groups from that match.

I could figure out how to ignore just the `.ini` group, but could not figure out how to get the regex to ignore all groups.  Can you please help me figure out the proper regex?

---

**Sample Input String**

A sample block of HTML code that I test the regex with.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Index of /images/AAVS</title>
 </head>
 <body>
<h1>Index of /images/AAVS</h1>
  <table>
   <tr><th valign="top"><img src="/icons/blank.gif" alt="[ICO]"></th><th><a href="?C=N;O=D">Name</a></th><th><a href="?C=M;O=A">Last modified</a></th><th><a href="?C=S;O=A">Size</a></th><th><a href="?C=D;O=A">Description</a></th></tr>
   <tr><th colspan="5"><hr></th></tr>
<tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/back.gif" alt="[PARENTDIR]"></td><td><a href="/images/">Parent Directory</a>       </td><td>&nbsp;</td><td align="right">  - </td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/folder.gif" alt="[DIR]"></td><td><a href="20190823/">20190823/</a>              </td><td align="right">2019-09-19 19:37  </td><td align="right">  - </td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/folder.gif" alt="[DIR]"></td><td><a href="20190826/">20190826/</a>              </td><td align="right">2019-09-19 19:31  </td><td align="right">  - </td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/unknown.gif" alt="[   ]"></td><td><a href="desktop.ini">desktop.ini</a>            </td><td align="right">2019-09-19 19:24  </td><td align="right">136 </td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
   <tr><th colspan="5"><hr></th></tr>
</table>
</body></html>
```

---

Also, I would like to say that I am sure there is a much better approach.  All critique is welcome!

Comment: [Parsing HTML with regex is a hard job](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/372239)
HTML and regex are not good friends. Use a parser, it is simpler, faster and much more maintainable.

Comment: Yes I did not know about that @Toto, that's perhaps a better long-term solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex is `(?<=href=")[^"]+(?<!\.ini)(?=")`

1. **`(?<=href=")`** Positive lookbehind of `href="`
2. **`[^"]+`** Match as many non-double quote characters as you can
3. **`(?<!\.ini)`** Negative lookbehind of `.ini`
4. **`(?=")`** Positive lookahead of a double quote

The code:

```
import re

html = """<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Index of /images/AAVS</title>
 </head>
 <body>
<h1>Index of /images/AAVS</h1>
  <table>
   <tr><th valign="top"><img src="/icons/blank.gif" alt="[ICO]"></th><th><a href="?C=N;O=D">Name</a></th><th><a href="?C=M;O=A">Last modified</a></th><th><a href="?C=S;O=A">Size</a></th><th><a href="?C=D;O=A">Description</a></th></tr>
   <tr><th colspan="5"><hr></th></tr>
<tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/back.gif" alt="[PARENTDIR]"></td><td><a href="/images/">Parent Directory</a>       </td><td>&nbsp;</td><td align="right">  - </td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/folder.gif" alt="[DIR]"></td><td><a href="20190823/">20190823/</a>              </td><td align="right">2019-09-19 19:37  </td><td align="right">  - </td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/folder.gif" alt="[DIR]"></td><td><a href="20190826/">20190826/</a>              </td><td align="right">2019-09-19 19:31  </td><td align="right">  - </td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/unknown.gif" alt="[   ]"></td><td><a href="desktop.ini">desktop.ini</a>            </td><td align="right">2019-09-19 19:24  </td><td align="right">136 </td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
   <tr><th colspan="5"><hr></th></tr>
</table>
</body></html>"""

l = re.findall(r'(?<=href=")[^"]+(?<!\.ini)(?=")', html, flags=re.I)
print(l)
```

Prints:

```
['?C=N;O=D', '?C=M;O=A', '?C=S;O=A', '?C=D;O=A', '/images/', '20190823/', '20190826/']
```

The above regex will accept any `href` value and that is why it returned values such as `'?C=N;O=D'`. If you wish to restrict it to values that are make up file and folder names that you are specifically looking for, you might use a more restrictive regex such as:

```
(?<=href=")[a-z0-9_./-]+(?<!\.ini)(?=")
```

This will result in printing:

```
['/images/', '20190823/', '20190826/']
```

But, in fact, based on my research, `?C=N;O=D` would be a legal filename in the Linux file system.

You can even accomplish the task without using lookbehind or lookahead:

```
l = [m.group(1) for m in re.finditer(r'(?:href=")([^"]+)(?:")', html, flags=re.I) if not m.group(1).lower().endswith(".ini")]
```

Comment: Thank you @RonaldAaronson!  Reading through your answer has also helped me properly grasp lookahead/lookbehind.  I thought of a minor improvement to the regex after seeing your answer.  I noticed that all directories end in `/`.  So the regex I use will be `(?<=href=")[a-z0-9._-]+(?=\/")`